# Weird Return value: mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find if the user has been allotted shares using mySql query. I have those queries in a function and it return 'No' all the time. However If I run the following queries at mySql command prompt I get 'Yes'. I have been breaking my head over this.. Very silly though.. Not able able to crack it. Any help would be appreciated. Thx!

```
//This returns 0 because the employee has been allotted shared now
//THIS IS THE MOST RECENT RECORD
SELECT ISNULL(NewEquityShares) INTO @PRESENT FROM System_Users_Share_Allotment_Info WHERE UserID = 'xyz' AND MostRecentRecord = 'Yes';

//This returns 1 because the employee was not allotted shared before
//THIS IS ONE RECORD BEFORE THE MOST RECENT RECORD
SELECT ISNULL(NewEquityShares) INTO @PREVIOUSLY FROM System_Users_Share_Allotment_Info WHERE UserID = 'xyz' AND MostRecentRecord = 'No';

//
SELECT IF ( @PRESENT = 0 AND @PREVIOUSLY = 1,'Yes','No');
```

mySQL Function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_isNewSharesAlloted`(UserID VARCHAR(36)) RETURNS VARCHAR(3) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

DECLARE strResponse VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE strUserID VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL;

SET strUserID = UserID;

    -- This returns 0 because the employee has been  allotted shared now
SELECT ISNULL(NewEquityShares) INTO @PRESENT FROM System_Users_Share_Allotment_Info WHERE UserID = strUserID AND MostRecentRecord = 'Yes';

    -- This returns 1 because the employee was not allotted shared before
SELECT ISNULL(NewEquityShares) INTO @PREVIOUSLY FROM System_Users_Share_Allotment_Info WHERE UserID = strUserID AND MostRecentRecord = 'No';

SELECT IF ( @PRESENT = 0 AND @PREVIOUSLY = 1,'Yes','No') INTO strResponse;

RETURN strResponse;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is `UserID` supposed to be hardcoded in your function?

Comment: No it is not hardcoded. Please see updated sql statement in the function

Comment: I don't see the point of either `strResponse` or `strUserID`.

Comment: Both are local variables - strResponse & strUserID

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. But they're both technically superfluous.

Comment: Is the `UserId` on `System_Users_Share_Allotment_Info` a `VARCHAR(36)` also?

Comment: @xpy - Is the UserId on System_Users_Share_Allotment_Info a VARCHAR(36) also? - Affirm